# php fpm error after upgrading

Tags: apache, php

I decided to do a aptitude safe upgrade today on my debian and it replaced my version of php with the latest.
It asked me if i want to keep my www.conf and i selected yes.

By this time, i see these errors in the error.log:

```
(13)Permission denied: FastCGI: failed to connect to server "/home/john/domains/test.net/php5-fpm": connect() failed
FastCGI: incomplete headers (0 bytes) received from server "/home/john/domains/test.net/php5-fpm"
```

And website is not accessible (php versions).

/home/john/domains/test.net/php5-fpm is not a directory at all.

I tried adding these lines to www.conf and restarting the service, with no luck:

```
listen.owner = www-data
listen.group = www-data
listen.mode = 0666
```

Please advise.

Comment: `www.conf` is the worker config, where you tell php which user and which socket to use. Do you have a value like this `listen = /var/run/php5-fpm.sock` ?

Comment: www.conf got this line: listen = 127.0.0.1:9000

however, there is another file john.conf which has this line in it: listen = /var/run/php5-fpm-john.sock

Probably php-fpm reads www.conf after the upgrade?

Comment: Wait.. your webservers configuratino is wrong, not PHP. Do you use Apache or nginx or lhttpd or ...? You need to configure it to connect to the socket created in the `pool.d` files. In nginx it's a value like `fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;`

Comment: It was working fine until the upgrade. I did, and restarted php5-fpm but its still not working.

Comment: The problem is that Apache can't connect to the PHP worker socket. I don't know the configuration for Apache. You can try to change `listen` param in www.conf or john.conf to `/home/john/domains/test.net/php5-fpm`.

Answer (score 0):

When you upgrade the Apache, the worker sometimes changes, execute `apachectl -V` and see what worker do you have installed.

For example in my local server i have MPM worker, and when i update via aptitude, the worker changes to prefork (don't know why), so i need to:

1. Executes `apachectl -V` and see what worker i have installed.
2. Executes `sudo apt-get install apache2-mpm-worker` if i detect i have prefork installed

In your case you will need to reinstall `php5-fpm`